# Tkinter change paste command

Tags: python, tkinter, paste

I'm trying to change paste command on my program. When we copy table value from excel, whether it's vertical or horizontal line, it will converted to vertical entries list. But the problem is when I only want to paste single value to the random entries line, it will always print the value from 1st line entry and not from the entry line that I selected. Is it also possible create function to select all entries with mouse?

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
d=[]
for i in range(4):
    e=Entry(root,)
    e.grid(row=i)
    d.append(e)

def paste(event):
    for entry in d:
        entry.delete(0,'end')
    data=root.clipboard_get().split()
    for entry,i in zip(d,data):
        if '\n':
            entry.insert(0, i.split('\n'))
            print(data)
        elif '\t':
            entry.insert(0, i.split('\t'))
            print(data)
    return 'break'

root.bind_all("<<Paste>>", paste)

root.mainloop()
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Thank you!!

Comment: `if '\n'` will always be evaluated as `True`.  What do you want actually on the two if checkings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the for loop always starts from the first entry box.  You need to find the index of the selected entry in the entry list `d` and paste the clipboard data starts from it:

```py
def paste(event):
    try:
        # get selected entry
        w = root.focus_get()
        # get the index of the selected entry in the entry list
        idx = d.index(w)
        # get the data from clipboard and split them into list
        data = root.clipboard_get()#.rstrip() # strip the trailing '\n'
        #print(repr(data)) # for debug purpose
        if '\t' in data:
            data = data.split('\t')
        elif '\n' in data:
            data = data.split('\n')
        # paste the data starts from the selected entry
        for entry, txt in zip(d[idx:], data):
            entry.delete(0, 'end')
            entry.insert('end', txt)
        return 'break'
    except Exception as ex:
        # something wrong, like no entry is selected
        print(ex)
```

Comment: Wow thanks. This is exactly what I'm looking for. But do you know how can we get index if there is 2 different entries widget in the same frame and list d append both of the entries for example d.append((e,e1))

Comment: Even the entries are in same frame, you can append them one by one.